# Is bad, from a SEO perspective, to have many pages on a website that only contain YouTube embedded videos?

Tags: seo, ranking, content

Will Google penalize my website for having plenty of pages that only contain YouTube embedded videos. Is this a bad idea SEO-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no penalty per se to having a page with an embedded video.  But without any other text or content, don't expect Google to rank the pages all that well.